# Why virtual keyboard does not work with QDialog textbox in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I make an application for keyboard less device.
I used [thisRef](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-tools-inputpanel-example.html) for keyboard as virtual keyboard.
I have a dialog in my project that has  two textboxes (one of them for enter user name and the other for input password ) with two buttons: OK and Cancel. after Build the project and run ,the press menu button to show menu form, then the dialog appears to check user authenticate. the user should enter data on text box the virtual  keyboard .
the virtual keyboard (input panel in [thisRef](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-tools-inputpanel-example.html) ) appears but the buttons not work.
when I searched I saw this ["sounds like you are trying to open another window from the dialog - this is your error. Of course the dialog will stay on top - that is its job."](http://www.qtforum.org/post/117735/what-is-the-correct-way-to-invoke-a-dialog-so-it-uses-a-qinputcontext.html#post117735)
because the dialog is modal, the virtual keyboard is disable
Is there anyway to edit the dialog or keyboard to work in modal widget?

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "myinputpanelcontext.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyInputPanelContext *ic= new MyInputPanelContext; ;
    a.setInputContext(ic);

    MainWindow w;
    //w.show();
    w.showFullScreen();
    w.centralWidget()->releaseKeyboard();
    return a.exec();
}
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```
MyDialog *d=new MyDialog(this);
d.exec();
```

Comment: Sounds like focus problem. But please provide better problem description in the question, so it is answerable without external links. Try to create a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to isolate the problem.

Comment: it solved: 1. Modal dialogs are started with exec(), they block the program flow while a nested event loop runs.
2. Modeless dialogs are started with show(), they do not block the program flow.

Comment: Voting to re-open, because there is a specific problem with virtual keyboard, and a solution for it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It solved:

Modal dialogs are started with exec(), they block the program flow while a nested event loop runs.
Modeless dialogs are started with show(), they do not block the program flow.

From http://www.qtforum.org/article/14285/modeless-dialog.html
I use this code :

```
 MyDialog *d=new MyDialog(this);
   d->show();
   d->raise();
   q->activewindows();
```

instead of this code:

```
MyDialog *d=new MyDialog(this);
   d.exec();
```

as the document reference :

> A modeless dialog: void EditorWindow::find() {

```
    if (!findDialog) {
>         findDialog = new FindDialog(this);
>         connect(findDialog, SIGNAL(findNext()), this, SLOT(findNext()));
>     } findDialog->show();
>     findDialog->raise();
>     findDialog->activateWindow(); }
```

> From [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html)

Comment: If you want a modal dialog that you can use the keyboard with, this doesn't really solve the problem, IIUC?